# how to loop a part of the code until value1 != value2?

Tags: php

I using this code to get a random numbers (length 9) and checking if on DB table exist row with that number, if it exist, will be generated a new number until it won't exist in a table:

code:

```
$random_numbers = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", 9)), 0, 9);

$Sql = "SELECT numer_zamowienia FROM zamowienia WHERE numer_zamowienia = '$random_numbers '";
$result_wartosc = $con->query($Sql);
```

Help me out...

Comment: [do - while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) should be practical here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop and break out of it when the query doesn't find a match.

```
while (true) {
    $random_numbers = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", 9)), 0, 9);
    $Sql = "SELECT 1 FROM zamowienia WHERE numer_zamowienia = '$random_numbers '";
    $result_wartosc = $con->query($Sql);
    if ($result_wartosc->num_rows == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
// Now you can insert $random_numbers into the table
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, a [`do-while loop`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) is likely what you are looking for. Your code would look something like this: (notice I also removed the extra space after `$random_numbers` in your SQL query string)

```
do {
    $random_numbers = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789", 9)), 0, 9);

    $Sql = "SELECT numer_zamowienia FROM zamowienia WHERE numer_zamowienia = '$random_numbers'";
    $result_wartosc = $con->query($Sql);

} while ($result_wartosc->num_rows > 0);
```